# facebook push realtime api for public page instead of manually checking

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

It seems weird that I can get a public page feed on facebook (posts, etc) by doing:

https://graph.facebook.com/cnn/feed?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN

but I can't get that info with their realtime api?  Is it possible just to have any changes (posts created) get pushed to me with the realtime api by subscribing to a page, for example the CNN facebook page?  It seems silly to just keep on having to hit the graph api every x minutes and check to see if there are any new posts since the last post id when the realtime api could just push them to me.  Does anyone know a way to do this?  What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to fetch the posts with PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: Using PHP.  I've tried things talked about over here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) but it seems I can only get realtime updates with people who have logged in with facebook connect to my app.  I want to get realtime updates (posts) of public pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to receive real time updates from the page, the app needs to be installed on the Page.

The real-time update settings doesn't let you specify a page_id so there is no way for Facebook to know which pages you want to receive updates from.

Seeing as you won't have permission to install apps to pages you don't have admin access to, you are limited to the method you are already using at the moment. The only way is to continue querying the API periodically and checking for changes.